# How add acf fields relationship ACF in the JSON wordpress api?

Tags: wordpress, relationship, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, wordpress-rest-api

I try to use wordpress API to build my back-office more easy. For this I must make relation between CPT UI post. I use the ACF and ACF recursive plugin for help me in this. But in the json 'http://localhost:10018/wp-json/wp/v2/plays' for example, i don't have the custom field ACF in my relation...

In this example i linked roles to the play and i want to have the ACF field for this item from staff post type.

[image]

I tried all the solutions in this topic : https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api/issues/223 But nothings happen...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, one of these should work now days. Seems to be a built in feature.

```
https://example.com/wp/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&_fields=title,acf

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=title,acf
```

The important bit being, adding `acf` to the list of fields and you should get an array of all the acf fields.

There is more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76573322/what-is-the-difference-between-rest-route-and-wp-json-in-wordpress-rest-api) about which approach above might be appropriate for your situation.