# What is the difference between rest_route and wp-json in Wordpress REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to build a WordPress plugin using the REST API instead of the complicated Setting API.
According to the documentation, the REST API is built on top of the `http://oursite.com/wp-json/` route. But the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#routes-vs-endpoints) also mentions this:

`On sites without pretty permalinks, the route is instead added to the URL as the rest_route parameter. For the above example, the full URL would then be http://example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/123`

Since `rest_route` works on both pretty and plain permalinks, I was thinking of sticking with `rest_route` instead of `wp-json`.

So my question is: is there a difference between the two routes?
What do you think guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`get_rest_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_rest_url/) will support pretty permalinks and the `rest_route` query parameter, so it really doesn't matter.

Pretty permalinks:

```php
get_rest_url( '/wp/v2/posts' ) === 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
```

Not pretty:

```php
get_rest_url( '/wp/v2/posts' ) === 'https://example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts'
```

Comment: This is even better. Thanks bro